# jQuery File Upload not Uploading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This PHP code works when I use HTML `<input type="file">`, but not when I use the jQuery file upload script at the very bottom.

1. I believe all .js & .css files are accounted for and working (tested)
2. I believe the **uploadUrl:** 'doc_upload.php', **fileInputName:** 'userfile' are correct. Don't know 'cause no errors are showing.
3. Using echo `getcwd();`, I believe I'm using correct paths
4. I'm only uploading a 1 kb .TXT file
5. I get no errors and all error reporting is on and maxed

One thing that is also not working, which I'm saying to possibly give a clue, is the upload & cancel buttons next to the file name are not showing all though clicking on them does seem to work.

Echo'ing $_POST shows me nothing on submit, but I think that's a javascript thing; not sure as I'm a beginner (3-months).

PHP page

```
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpname  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmpname'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp = fopen($tmpname, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $filename = addslashes($filename);
    }

    $filename = preg_replace('/[ ]/', '~', $filename);

    $document_folder = $_SESSION['users_id'];
    $destfile = "../_documents/".$document_folder."/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmpname'], $destfile );
```

HTML page

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../jqx.base.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jqwidgets/jqxfileupload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#jqxFileUpload').jqxFileUpload({ width: 300, uploadUrl: 'doc_upload_jquery.php', fileInputName: 'userfile', autoUpload: true });
        });



    $('#jqxFileUpload').on('uploadStart', function (event) {
            var fileName = event.args.file;
            $('#log').prepend('Started uploading: <strong>' + fileName + '</strong><br />');
    });



    $('#jqxFileUpload').on('remove', function (event) {
            var fileName = event.args.file;
        $('#log').prepend('Removed file: <strong>' + fileName + '</strong><br />');

    });



    $('#jqxFileUpload').on('uploadEnd', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        var fileName = args.file;
        var serverResponce = args.response;
    });



</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="jqxFileUpload">
</div>
<div id="log" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you properly write `enctype` attribute in `form` tag ?

Comment: From what I can see, there is no form requirement on my part. Of all the examples I've seen, I've not seen one with a form tag. And, when I do add form tag, it breaks the jQuery. Thanks ...

Comment: check for errors, check your console and make sure the folder has the right permissions to write to it, and that the session was started.

Comment: `<input type="file">` if that's your full input, it needs an id and/or name attribute. Show your code where you have that submit button, or see the answers given below.

Comment: all that's requested is:  uploadUrl: 'doc_upload_jquery.php', fileInputName: 'userfile'. There is not HTML <input type='file'> required on my part.

Answer (score 0):

mdpalow -

You probably aren't getting any errors or output because of the if statement at the top:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['userfile']) {
```

Try putting this at the top to output all of your post variables so that you can determine what post variables are actually being sent (if any):

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I have done file uploads before but not with this specific library - my guess is that its just sending mulipart data instead of POST variables. Looking at the preview headers in the browser developer tools will also shed light as to what data is being sent.

Comment: In my OP, I said I don't think I'm actually $_POST'ing, which may have been confirmed by answer posted above. I put it in again per your suggestion and will leave it there for now, but still nothing showing.

Comment: using the dev tools in chrome was a good idea. it's showing me some things. I've stripped php portion to bare min. and getting error: Undefined index: tmpname.

<?php session_start();

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < 1024000)  {

  $tmpname  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmpname'];
  $document_folder = $_SESSION['users_id'];
  $destfile = "../_documents/".$document_folder."/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmpname'], $destfile );

}

  print_r($_FILES);
?>

Comment: Check out the documentation for the $_FILES global here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

I think the the index should be 'tmp_name' instead of 'tmpname'.

Comment: Both you and samarkand gave some good answers. However, it was your suggestion to use the built-in browser dev tool, which I've never done, that ultimately started giving me a lot of clues. Finally, decided to break it down to lowest form and found: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. Put that in and everything started working. Dev tool helped me iron it all out to include part 2 of my OP about images. I like where I'm at right now albeit I can't get the page to refresh with header to show the newly loaded file, but I want to google that more to see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery plugin uploads file via AJAX. In order to fix the issue please follow next steps:

- Keep your HTML and PHP code in separate files.
- In new PHP file remove isset($_POST['submit']) validation as there is no submission.

Comment: done. all errors that were showing when I took out $_POST went away as soon as I separated the php from the rest of code. However, still no magic in terms of any files being uploaded.